# How to alter the datatypes of multiple fields only if the fields exist

Tags: ms-access, alter

I have a number of different files with different fields.
I am trying to mass-update the field types in a SQL view of MS Access and I am getting errors because all of the files have different fields.
Is there a way to create a modify/alter query that disregards fields if they don't exist in the table and only update them if they exist?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need VBA for this.

Comment: *I am trying...I am getting errors* ... Please show attempted code.